# What after 2013/5/19?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Do you know how shutdown of Google Maps API 2 will be carried out? There will be kind of alert instead of an application?

There is not much information about it on their website
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has been announced yet. Announcements about the Google Maps API go out through the blog: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/ I recommend upgrading now.

Comment: Sure, I will. All I need to do is to explain it to my customers somehow:)

Comment: Explain to them that their website might stop working in May