# Google maps API V2 May 2013

Tags: google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Maps API Ver2 retired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180774/google-maps-api-ver2-retired)

Does anyone know what will happen to the Google Maps V2 api on the 19th May 2013? Will it simply stop working? 
Will all apps using the V2 api stop working?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174599/what-after-2013-5-19 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180774/google-maps-api-ver2-retired